# Hide navbar when li element is been clicked on

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I'm having trouble hiding the navbar when we click on one of the element like contact or something.. I'm using HTML, JS and CSS..

````
        <div class="theme">
            <img class="darkThemeicon" src="assets/front/img/moon.png" alt="moon dark mode" id="icon">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="ul">
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#project">Project</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>```


    ```const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
    hamburger.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const ul = document.querySelector('nav > ul');
        ul.classList.toggle('menu-slide');
        hamburger.classList.toggle('cross');
    });
    
    function hideDiv() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('ul')[0].style.display = "none";
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code does not include any part that would react to a click on the `li` elements. I have added the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => li.addEventListener('click', hideDiv));
```

```js
const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
    hamburger.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const ul = document.querySelector('nav > ul');
        ul.classList.toggle('menu-slide');
        hamburger.classList.toggle('cross');
    });
    
    function hideDiv() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('ul')[0].style.display = "none";
    }
    
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => li.addEventListener('click', hideDiv));
```

```html
      <header>
      <div class="theme">
            <img class="darkThemeicon" src="assets/front/img/moon.png" alt="moon dark mode" id="icon">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="ul">
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#project">Project</a></li>
                <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: But I just want to toggle stuff to disappear and not all of it.. Cause it's only for the phone screen that I want that to not show.. Atm even on desktop, once I clicked on a linked they all disappear..

Comment: Hmm, once a link is clicked you want the UL to be hidden but only if the user is on a narrow screen size (like a phone) otherwise you want it to remain visible?

Comment: Yes.. I mean like any collapsed nav bar in a phone.; When you click on the link then you go to the page but the navbar doesn't stay there.. You know what I mean?

Comment: In order for me to keep helping you will need to post whatever CSS you have. Since if I understand correctly you are looking for advice on how to create a mobile side-drawer navigation panel that can be shown and hidden on click of something... like a hamburger button?

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need to call Your function in the HTML Code

```
 <ul class="ul">
            <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#home" onclick="hideDiv()">Home</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#skills" onclick="hideDiv()">Skills</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#project" onclick="hideDiv()">Project</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a class="list-link" href="#contact" onclick="hideDiv()">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```